# Android MediaPlayer stops working after a while

Tags: java, android, xamarin, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am playing a sound with this method:

```
public async Task<bool> PlaySound(string fileName)
{
    bool done = false;

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();


    sw.Start();

    var fd = Assets.OpenFd(fileName);

    mp.Prepared += (sender, e) =>
    {
        mp.Start();
    };

    mp.Error += (sender, e) =>
    {
        done = true;
    };

    mp.Completion += (sender, e) =>
    {
        done = true;
    };


    mp.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.DeclaredLength);

    mp.Prepare();

    while (done == false && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000)
        await Task.Delay(100);

    return true;
}

private async void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (recorder.recording == true)
    {
        await PlaySound("saving_video.mp3");
        recorder.SavePerm();
    }
    else
        await PlaySound("the_camera_is_not_currently_recording.mp3");
}
```

I also have an instance of `SpeechRecognizer` running and `MediaRecorder` to record the camera.

After a while of giving the same voice command to the speech recognizer.

Every time it goes to play a sound by creating a new instance of `MediaPlayer` with

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

I get the following java error in the debug log:

```
08-01 22:38:42.151 E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(22934): env->IsInstanceOf fails
08-01 22:38:42.151 E/MediaPlayer-JNI(22934): JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
08-01 22:38:42.151 E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(22934): env->IsInstanceOf fails
08-01 22:38:42.151 E/MediaPlayer-JNI(22934): JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

Every time it tries to play a sound.

No exception is thrown and the program continues to execute, but no sound is played again until the service is restarted.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should probably dispose of the MediaPlayer after you are done with it. Or reuse it to play the next sound.

Comment: It should get automatically disposed by the garbage collector once it goes out of scope shouldn't it? I switched it to creating the players statically to get around this issue, but I don't know what is the root cause.

Comment: Did you try to call  `mediaplayer.Stop();` and `mediaplayer.Release();`after using it.

Comment: You are actually holding on to it indirectly by assigning event handlers to events.